# Enable CORS for multiple customers

Tags: cors

We use .htaccess file for controlling access:

Currently, we have the following code to allow CORS to our developer APIs:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api/v1/#">
            Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
</If>
```

Now, we don't want iframes or other 3rd parties to be able to call our APIs.

How can we maintain the whitelisted origins to be allowed for CORS. Maintaining manually .htaccess file by adding removing origins for every new customer sounds complicated. What would be the recommended way to  maintain list of whitelisted origins.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You do want restrict access to specific customers but you don't want do maintain a list of such customers manually? In this case the best way would probably to extract the necessary information from some (unknown) system where you already somehow manage your customers. But this does not really look like a security problem for me and apart from the the details would depend on how you manage your customers currently which is unknown to us.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your comment. What kind of external system can we use to store the whitelist to be used by .htaccess

Comment: If you have customers you usually have some system where you manage information about your customers since you need this for billing and for contacting your customers, i.e. a CRM. This is not a special system for .htacess only but it might be possible to maintain the necessary information (domain) in the CRM and have some scripting to extract it to feed your server setup and web application. But none of this is actually a topic of information security but a question on how to automatically create files from information in CRM, i.e. the question it is off-topic.